# Plain text from PDF using Air/ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, pdf, air

Is there a way to extract plain text from a PDF file using ActionScript? If not, can you give me some hints on how it is implemented elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any existing actionscript library for parsing/extracting text from PDF's (as it'd be too cumbersome doing that in it). But you can use [xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/), which is implemented in C/C++, which comes with pdftotext.